# Lightweight fast PHP Logging

Tags: php, logging, lamp

Suppose we need to log some data on every php call on each request being made to the server on a high traffic- request heavy web application, to basically trace the actions taken by each client.
I was considering saving them to memory and then logging all in one go to prevent frequent disk access.
Is there a Php framework which already does this which I can reuse?
I need to do this on the actual production server so I dont want to use stuff like xdebug.

Comment: I would do it with a database, if well configured it won't add too much server load.

Comment: Maybe one of these offer what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341154/php-logging-framework

Answer (score 1):

**[Redis](http://redis.io/)** would be my suggestion.

There is a php library [Rediska](http://rediska.geometria-lab.net/), that makes use of Redis server. At some point data can be dumped to db, i.e. when server load isn't at it highest.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `apc_store`, i use it for light php request time analyzer

https://gist.github.com/aiphee/8004486cbd37b3f13efd271b8457cb38